# Cygwin error message -- binary file not executable

Tags: unix, cygwin, runtime-error

So I am trying to install a program on my windows machine that required me to install Cygwin to install it.  So I am working from a README file and assueme I have compiled the code previously correctly (its one line sh build.sh) and when actually trying to use the program I get the following error:

```
BabakP@Babak /cygdrive/c/Users/BabakP/Desktop/test
$ ./Runlock input.tst output.tst 1
./Ostrich: Exec format error. Binary file not executable.
```

I guess I am trying to figure out why I am getting this error so any suggestions on how to troubleshoot it would be great!

Comment: What does `file ./Runlock` tell you?

Comment: Its an file that computes a function.  Like it takes in an input file (input.tst) and spits out and output file (output.tst).  When I say its a function I literally mean it evaluates something like f(x) where x is the inpute file.

Comment: No, I mean what output do you get when you type `file ./Runlock` at your shell prompt? CORRECTION: Now that I read your question more closely, what does `file ./Ostrich` tell you?

Comment: `$ file ./Ostrich`
`./Ostrich: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable`

Comment: So there's your problem; `Ostrich` isn't a Windows or Cygwin executable. Where did that file come from?

Comment: I was given it (obviously now from a Mac user).  Is there anything I can download to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`./Ostrich` is a Mac executable. It can't be executed under Cygwin. (A MacOS emulator that runs under Windows or Cygwin is theoretically possible, but I don't know of any such thing.)

Without knowing the details of the software you're trying to install, it's hard to say how or whether you can fix it.

You may be able to rebuild `Ostrich` from source (if you have the source, and if it's not MacOS-specfic).

Comment: Not to ask a dumb question but how would I rebuild it from source?

Comment: @StatMan: I don't know. If it's a publicly available software package, update your question with the URL where you got it. Or talk to the author.